# Trap function by passing arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, signals, bash-trap

I've been searching everywhere and I've come to believe that there is no way to do that other than having global variables but I believe the guru's in stackoverflow.com may be able to help me:

Is there any way in bash to trap a function by passing arguments to it?
For example, `trap <function_name> <arg_1> <arg_2> SIGINT`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`trap` lets you specify an arbitrary command (or sequence of commands), but you have to pass that command as a single argument. For example, this:

```
trap 'foo bar baz | bip && fred barney ; wilma' SIGINT
```

will run this:

```
foo bar baz | bip && fred barney ; wilma
```

whenever the shell receives SIGINT. In your case, it sounds like you want:

```
trap '<function> <arg_1> <arg_2>' SIGINT
```

Comment: Actually it didn't work since calling trap "myfunction $arg_1 $arg_2" SIGINT SIGTERM meant that when Ctrl-C was pressed the old values of $arg_1 $arg_2 where preserved and not the updates ones. Guess I'll use  a wrapper function or make the arguments global since I can't make that work the way I intended to :/ P.S.: Does it matter that I used double_quotes and not single as in your example?

Comment: @Kounavi: As you guessed -- you need to use single-quotes, not double-quotes.

Comment: Yeap! Single quotes did the job! Probably my plugin in gVim needs to be updated because I have bash support and I thought it would be "colored properly" if it was correct. Mucho gracias pal! :)

Comment: @Kounavi: You're welcome! To clarify, single-quotes and double-quotes both delimit strings, but double-quotes allow backslash-processing and parameter-expansion within the string, whereas single-quotes do not. So, for example, if the variable `$x` is an asterisk, then `echo $x` lists files in the current directory, `echo "$x"` prints an asterisk, and `echo '$x'` prints a dollar sign and an X.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind too since it sounds useful information :]

Comment: It would be useful to know what scope the code given to `trap` is being run in i.e. if one can pass local variables this way.

Comment: Is it possible to pass the exit code or check the exit code inside the trap function?

Comment: The exit code of X where X is in `exit X`. But I figured it out. Just use `$?`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but ... this is legal:

```
trap "cp /etc/passwd $HOME/p" SIGINT
trap 'cp /etc/passwd /tmp/p; echo wooo hoo' SIGINT
```

Comment: Only single quotes worked with variables of type $arg1, $arg2 etc. But, yes that's what I needed! ;)

Comment: I'm glad Michal explained it so thoroughly and that you got it worked out. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand correctly what you mean, but if you want to make a signal handler call a function and pass it parameters, `trap "function arg1 arg2" SIGNAL` should work. For example `trap "ls -lh /" INT` will cause Ctrl+C in your shell to result in `ls -lh /` (program with 2 args) being called.

Comment: Actually I was not using quotes and it was not working. Thanks for your help :]

Comment: Update: Still it doesn't (check my comments in top post)

Comment: Just change double to single quotes and the expansion will be delayed until the trap command is executed, for example with `trap 'echo "$PATH"' INT`  any changes to PATH will be visible to the trap function.